# How to Convert var to string?

Tags: c#, parsing, windows-phone-8

**How to Convert var to string?**
In my windowsphone application page, i want to convert this var **DemoHeader**  to a string.

---

```
XDocument myData = XDocument.Load("aarti.xml");

var DemoHeader = from query in myData.Descendants("bookinfo")
                 select new HeaderT
                 {
                     Header = (string)query.Element("header")
                 };


ContentHeaderLine.Text = DemoHeader.ToString();‏ //LINE GIVING WRONG DATA

public class HeaderT
{
    string header;
    public string Header
    {
        get { return header; }
        set { header = value; }
    }    
}
```

---

How can i convert   **var DemoHeader** to a string?

Comment: override ToString method in class HeaderT

Comment: What does "Giving wrong data" mean? You need to explain what behaviour you receive and what you expect... either way it looks like Roman is correct.

Answer (score 3):

First, `var` is not a type by itself, the type will be inferred from the value by the compiler. Your type is actually `HeaderT` and your query returns an `IEnumerable<HeaderT>` (so possibly multiple).

Presuming you want the first header:

```
HeaderT first = DemoHeader.First();
string firstHeader = first.Header();
```

or you want all returned separated by comma:

```
string allHeaders = String.Join(",", DemoHeader.Select(dh => dh.Header()));
```

If you want that `ToString` returns something meaningful(instead of name of the type), [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) it:

```
public class HeaderT
{
    private string header;
    public string Header
    {
        get { return header; }
        set { header = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Header;
    }
}
```

Comment: As an alternative to overriding `ToString`, `dh => dh.Header()` could be replaced with `dh => dh.Header().GetStringIWant()`.

Comment: My point was more that he didn't have to override `ToString()` if he stopped calling it instead.  I hadn't noticed that his original question was calling `ToString()` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Override ToString() in HeaderT class could help. After that, you DemoHeader variable is a list of HeaderT not a single HeaderT.